# Custom headers not received in nodejs while using nginx reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx, http-headers, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have nodejs and nginx running i am sending an additional header in the API 'api_key' and its not received in `req.headers` and `req.get('api_key')` in nodejs i have bellow configuration file for nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name mysite.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
 location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9102/;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header api_key $http_api_key; 
    #proxy_set_header api_key 'Some Value'; works 
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

If set the value of `proxy_set_header api_key 'some value'` it works and headers are printed on console but the `api_key` is subjected to change that's why i am using `$http_api_key` so that whatever comes in `api_key` custom header is received as it is sent from rest client. I have tried couple of solutions like `proxy_set_header api_key $upstream_http_api_key;` but no help. I want to receive any custom header sent from rest client in nodejs.

Comment: Add `proxy_pass_header api_key;` and not set it yourself. See if that helps

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default, `nginx` does not pass headers containing underscores.

Try:

```
underscores_in_headers on;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers) for details.

*Alternatively, use `API-KEY` or `X-API-KEY` instead of `API_KEY`.*

Comment: Is there some similar config for node.js server running via forever? This is how we run our application - `/bin/forever start -o logs/out.log -e logs/err.log app.js`.

Comment: im having similar issues, i added underscores_in_headers on; but still undefined... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51265803/nginx-proxy-set-header-does-not-pass-req-header-to-backend-undefined-req-heade